# Different Colors inside VisualStudio 2012 output window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, node.js, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Is it really possible to have Visual Studio 2012 output window display the custom message in different colors?

I am displaying the errors/warnings from the Node console onto VS output window and I can get the messages displayed but the color codes are ansi format and gets rendered onto the output window as codes.

I know there are some extensions available but i am looking for a way to have the ansi color codes getting displayed as proper colors inside VS 2012.

Any help is appreciated !!

Thanks.

Comment: Bill Gregg,, not really helping I guess...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`VSCommands for Visual Studio 2012`](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a83505c6-77b3-44a6-b53b-73d77cba84c8) will do this for you. It will let you change the colours for errors and so forth. (It also has some other very useful features, so it's well worth installing IMHO. Works fine with Resharper.)

Comment: Thanks  Matthew. i need to see if this supports ansi color code conversion. Will explore this.

Comment: @Bhargava, I'm VSCommands author, let me know what you mean exactly by ansi color code coversion and I'll add support for it (Jarek@squaredinfinity.com)

Comment: @JarekKardas: I have a custom MS build task which executes nodejs tasks and returns the response to be displayed in VS output window. NodeJS uses a plugin called color which helps in adding different colors to the messages being rendered on the command line.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment.  @JarekKardas: I have a custom MS build task which executes nodejs tasks and returns the response to be displayed in VS output window. NodeJS uses a plugin called color which helps in adding different colors to the messages being rendered on the command line. On Command line everything appears fine as it is able to understand the    ansi color codes. When the same message gets displayed in VS output window it gets displayed as ansi code itself. Thanks for your response and Sorry for the delay in responding to your email.

Comment: ok, I think I know what you mean now. I haven't used ansi color codes myself, so if you could email me example output to Jarek@squaredinfinity.com then it would be great. The biggest problem will probably be not changing colors but hiding escape codes from output, but I'll have a dig around to see how this can be done. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The ANSI colours are not supported by Visual Studio itself.

You could  install the [VSColorOutput](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4d9c2b5-d6d7-4543-a7a5-2d7ebabc2496) extension to get some basic colours supported. You can also download the [code](http://vscoloroutput.codeplex.com/) and modify it to meet the requirements.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with the out-of-the-box implementation, then you can [download the VSColorOutput source](http://vscoloroutput.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your response Steve. I guess this doesn't solve my purpose as it has few color codes pre-defined and doesn't recognize all of the ansi color formats.

Comment: Thanks Karl... Will certainly look into that. Looks like need to write some VS extensions to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

A simple Visual Studio extension will do this for you: [VSColorOutput](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4d9c2b5-d6d7-4543-a7a5-2d7ebabc2496)